# Как удалить динамически созданный LineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

Я хочу иметь возможность удалить добавленный LineEdit.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код динамических LineEdit:

qdynamiclineedit.h

```
#ifndef QDYNAMICLINEEDIT_H
#define QDYNAMICLINEEDIT_H
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>

class QDynamicLineEdit : public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QDynamicLineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QDynamicLineEdit();
    int getID();
    static int ResID;
private:
    int LineEditID = 0;
};

#endif // QDYNAMICLINEEDIT_H
```

qdynamiclineedit.cpp

```
#include "qdynamiclineedit.h"    
QDynamicLineEdit::QDynamicLineEdit(QWidget *parent):
    QLineEdit(parent)
{
    ResID++;
    LineEditID = ResID;
    //QDynamicLineEdit::installEventFilter(parent);
}   
QDynamicLineEdit::~QDynamicLineEdit() { 
}   
int QDynamicLineEdit::getID() {
    return LineEditID;
}   
int QDynamicLineEdit::ResID = 0;
```

Сам код формы и добавления поля в журнал:

addlog.h

```
#ifndef ADDLOG_H
#define ADDLOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "qdynamiclineedit.h"

namespace Ui {
class AddLog;
}

class AddLog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit AddLog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~AddLog();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_2_clicked();
    void on_pushButton_3_clicked();
    void on_lineEdit_returnPressed();
    bool eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event);
    void SetNumberLineEdit();

private:
    Ui::AddLog *ui;
    QDynamicLineEdit* FieldLineEdit;
};

#endif // ADDLOG_H
```

addlog.cpp

```
#include "addlog.h"
#include "ui_addlog.h"
#include <QDebug>

AddLog::AddLog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::AddLog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit->setText("введите_название_журнала");
}

AddLog::~AddLog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void AddLog::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    FieldLineEdit = new QDynamicLineEdit(this);
    FieldLineEdit->setText(QString("введите_название_поля_%1").arg(FieldLineEdit->getID()));
    ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(FieldLineEdit);
    //FieldLineEdit->installEventFilter(this);
    //connect(FieldLineEdit, SIGNAL(), this, SLOT(SetNumberLineEdit()));
}

bool AddLog::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(watched == FieldLineEdit) {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
             ui->lineEdit_2->setText(QString("%1").arg(FieldLineEdit->getID()));
        }
    }
    //return AddLog::eventFilter(watched, event);
}

void AddLog::SetNumberLineEdit() {
    ui->lineEdit_2->setText(QString("%1").arg(FieldLineEdit->getID()));
}

void AddLog::on_pushButton_3_clicked()
{

}

void AddLog::on_lineEdit_returnPressed()
{
    qDebug()<<"1";
}
```

Определение события клика на LineEdit, которое я попробовал сделать. Просто скрывает все LineEdite, кроме последнего добавленного:

```
... 
QDynamicLineEdit::installEventFilter(parent);
...
bool AddLog::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(watched == FieldLineEdit) {
        if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress) {
             ui->lineEdit_2->setText(QString("%1").arg(FieldLineEdit->getID()));
        }
    }
    //return AddLog::eventFilter(watched, event);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не понял, в чем вопрос-то? В заголовке про событие, в начале текста про удаление, потом какая-то простыня кода и какие-то скриншоты. Задайте конкретный вопрос. З.Ы. не называйте ваши кастомные виджеты QWhatever, с Q начинаются встроенный виджеты кьюта. Запутаетесь. З.З.Ы. Для добавления поля id в ваш lineedit не надо его сабклассить, достаточно воспользоваться методом setProperty

Comment: @Bearded Beaver Мне надо удалить Line Edit который я выберу. Как это сделать?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, храните в контейнере ваши line_edit'ы, например: массив, список, словарь. Когда будете удалять, из контейнера достанете ссылку/указательно на line_edit и вызовите у него deleteLater

Comment: @gil9red Проблема в событиях. Я не понимаю как отловить событие нажатие на LineEdit. Описано выше в чём проблема.  LineEdit скрываются, если передавать в них FieldLineEdit->installEventFilter(this); Если есть конкретное решение можно написать его ?

Comment: В смысле скрываются? Попробуйте сделать installEventFilter и логировать все события, отфильтровывая сначала те, что по типу приходят (MouseButtonPress), а после те что по самим объектам

Comment: @gil9red Я это и делаю. Если вы посмотрите на два скриншота , которые я прикрепил , то там прекрасно видно, что Line Edit отображается только последний

Comment: Так давайте еще раз. on_pushButton_2_clicked() создает новые lineEdit'ы? Но переменная FieldLineEdit  хранит только последний созданный таким образом lineEdit? И в eventFilter'е вы проверяете что прослушиваемый виджет будет последний lineEdit? А еще вы не вызываете AddLog::eventFilter и это может что-нибудь сломать ([пример eventFilter](https://github.com/gil9red/ContainerExes/blob/236c82cb7798df23a763e9f5f136fe3b6a4bfe02/ULineEditWithButton/ULineEditWithClearButton.h#L122), [больше примеров](https://github.com/search?l=C%2B%2B&q=user%3Agil9red+eventFilter&type=Code))

Comment: @gil9red on_pushButton_2_clicked() Создаёт LineEdit-ы , но если добавить в QDynamicLineEdit: "QDynamicLineEdit::installEventFilter(parent);" То виден только последний Line Edit. Если не добавлять "QDynamicLineEdit::installEventFilter(parent);"  то тогда не понятно как отловить событие нажатия на Line Edit

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76216/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-gil9red).

Comment: Хранить в списке добавленные lineEdit'ы. Создаете в классе `QList<QLineEdit*>`, при добавлении lineEdit на форму добавляете его в тот список. В eventFilter'е проверяете что watched есть в том списке